# get values entered on jsp to action class

Tags: java, jsp, input, struts, action

How Can I get the value when I type something new into the jsp and then submit the list to the actionclass? Currently I am able to submit to the action class from the jsp and see the new list that I create inside my action. But I would like to be able to retirieve the values that I type into the jsp.

Employee object class:

```
public class Employee {
    String empid;
    String empname;

        public String getEmpid() {
            return empid;
        }

        public void setEmpid(String empid) {
            this.empid = empid;
        }

        public String getEmpname() {
            return empname;
        }

        public void setEmpname(String empname) {
            this.empname = empname;
        }

        public Employee(String empid, String empname) {
            this.empid = empid;
            this.empname = empname;
        }



    }
```

Employee JSP:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-    8859-1"%>
    <%@ include file="../imports.jsp" %>  
     @page import="java.util.List"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> Struts Logic Iterate Tag</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffcc66">
<html:form action="/logiciterate" styleId="LogicIterateForm" method="post"> 

    <h1>Struts logic:iterate tag </h1>
      <table style="font-weight:bold">
        <tr><td>Employee ID</td>
        <td>Employee Name</td></tr>


    <logic:iterate name="LogicIterateForm" property="emp" id="employee">
            <tr>
                    <td><html:text name="employee" value="${employee.empid}"          property="empid"
                            indexed="true" /></td>
                    <td><html:text name="employee" value="${employee.empname}"
                            property="empname" indexed="true" /></td>
            </tr>
    </logic:iterate>
```

```
            <input type="submit"  id="submit" value="Submit"   title="Submit" name="Submit"   >
```

```
            </html:form>
</body>
```

Action Class:

```
    public class LogicIterateAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

private final static String SUCCESS = "success";


public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

   if(request.getParameter("Submit") == null) {          

                                LogicIterateForm formBean=(LogicIterateForm)form;
                               ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                                list.add(new Employee("11A0","Jack"));
                                list.add(new Employee("11A1","Sam"));
                                list.add(new Employee("11A2","Joe"));
                                list.add(new Employee("11A3","John"));
                                formBean.setEmp(list);
                                    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);

}



else{

     LogicIterateForm formBean=(LogicIterateForm)form;
      ArrayList<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                list2.add(new Employee("673","Queenie"));
                list2.add(new Employee("123","Wally"));
                list2.add(new Employee("345","Spike"));
                list2.add(new Employee("564","Red"));
                formBean.setEmp(list2);



     return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);

}


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how abt this 
Step1...
    writing msg  in action class..
        example--
            request.setAttribute("message", "User deleted successfully");

Step2...
    gettng msg in jsp page..
        example--
            <%= request.getAttribute("message") %>

are u searching for this

Comment: no, when I type bob, sally, sue, etc. into the jsp I want to get those values back to the action class so that on submit when the page is reloaded I see whatever I typed into the inputs on the jsp instead of the default values

Comment: how abt creating object for the bean and getting those values

Answer (score 0):

Use the example below.

In JSP:

```
<logic:iterate name="monthlyGainLossForm" property="ptcList" id="productTaxCat">
    <html:hidden name="productTaxCat" property="ptcId" indexed="true" />
    <html:hidden name="productTaxCat" property="ptcName" indexed="true" />
    <html:hidden name="productTaxCat" property="ptcActive" indexed="true" />
    <mf:tr>
        <mf:td><bean:write name="productTaxCat" property="ptcName"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><bean:write name="productTaxCat" property="ptcActive"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="msaPtcLtcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="msaPtcLtcGLAmt" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" disabled="true" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="msaMthlyStcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="msaMthlyStcGLAmt" disabled="true" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaPtcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaPtcGLAmt" disabled="true" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:checkbox name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaStcGLType" styleClass="input" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
        <mf:td><html:text name="productTaxCat" property="nonMsaStcGLAmt" disabled="true" styleClass="label" style="width:100px;vertical-align:middle;" indexed="true"/></mf:td>
    </mf:tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

In action:

```
for(int m = 0; m < monthGainLossForm.getPtcList().size(); m++) {
    ProductTaxCat prodTaxCat = (ProductTaxCat)monthGainLossForm.getPtcList().get(m);

    if(prodTaxCat.getMsaMthlyStcGLType()) {
        selectedPtcTypeCounter++;
    }

    if(prodTaxCat.getMsaPtcLtcGLType()) {
        selectedPtcTypeCounter++;
    }

    if(prodTaxCat.getNonMsaPtcGLType()) {
        selectedPtcTypeCounter++;
    }

    if(prodTaxCat.getNonMsaStcGLType()) {
        selectedPtcTypeCounter++;
    }
}
```